# DiscordJS : Issue with Userinfo command

Tags: javascript, momentjs, discord.js

I'm making a DiscordJS Bot and I have an issue with my `userinfo` command. 
I want to know when the user joins the guild, and it replies with the date of today. I'm sure the user didn't join today.
Here's my code

```js
const user = message.mentions.users.first() || bot.users.cache.get(args[0]) || message.author;
if (!user) return message.channel.send("Utilisateur introuvable")
  .then(message => {
    message.delete({
      timeout: 3000
    })
  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
  });

const userStatus = {
  online: "<:Online:697378421319270401> En ligne",
  idle: "<:Idle:697378421130395749> Inactif",
  dnd: "<:DND:697378421386248282> Ne pas déranger",
  offline: "<:Off:697378421264875594> Hors ligne"
}

if (user.bot) {
  isBot = "Oui";
} else {
  isBot = "Non";
}

const uiEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(user.username)
  .setColor(message.member.displayHexColor)
  .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL({
    dynamic: true
  }))
  .addField("Pseudo et Tag", "<:Discord:697378425178030171> " + user.tag, true)
  .addField("Surnom", `${message.guild.members.resolveID(user.id).nickame || "Aucun Surnom"}`, true)
  .addField("ID", "<:ID:697380447876808716> " + user.id, true)
  .addField("Bot ?", "<:Bot:697378421163950152> " + isBot, true)
  .addField("Compte créé le :", "<:Dis:697380487785873499> " + moment(user.createdAt).format("LL"), true)
  .addField("Status", userStatus[user.presence.status], true)
  .addField(Compte créé le: , moment(message.guild.members.resolveID(user.id).joinedAt).format("LL"), true)
  .setFooter(`Commande effectuée par ${message.author.username} | Azaziell`)
message.channel.send(uiEmbed);
```

As you can see in my code, it's a French bot ^^" So, the issue is in the line that says `Compte créé le :`
And I'm using the version 12.1.1 of discord.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you defined user is getting the info for the user, you need to specify you want the info for the user in the guild, so do this instead:

```
    let member = message.guild.member(message.author);

    console.log(member.joinedAt);
```

This gives me the result I assume you want:

```
2020-05-02T12:36:53.445Z
```

wich you can then format